# SQL Server Incorrect syntax msg 102

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Register 
    (@Name NVARCHAR(50),
     @Email NVARCHAR(50),
     @Password NVARCHAR(50),
     @Created DATETIME, )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Register] (Name, Email, Password, Created)
    VALUE (@Name, @Email, @Password, GETDATE())
END
GO
```

I keep getting these error messages:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Register, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Register, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'value'.

Can anybody help?

Comment: its `values` not `value`. Sometimes your compiler helps a lot see the error itself shown by the compiler incorrect syntax near `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your stored procedure.

First, as answered by others, it should be 'values' not value. However, after you fix this, you will get few other compiler error. You have put few brackets extra and comma extra. Please see below working copy of your stored procedure. Hope this will help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Register 
    @Name NVARCHAR(50),
    @Email NVARCHAR(50),
    @Password NVARCHAR(50),
    @Created DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Register] (Name, Email, Password, Created)
    VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Password, GETDATE())
END
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know why there are loads of stored procedures under system stored procedures

Comment: Hi Joe, In SQL server many administrative tasks are performed by using system stored procedures. Few of them SQL server uses for its specific purposes and few others users can also use it. You can find more info on MSDN. If you get the correct answer of your question appreciate if you can accept the answer, so that other users can also refer it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `values`Instead `value`

```
insert into [dbo].[Register] (Name, Email, Password, Created)
values (@Name, @Email, @Password, GETDATE())
```

Comment: thank you, do you know what to do about the syntax error with the closing bracket

Comment: @Joe it throws that error because of using wrong keyword

Comment: what do i need to change then? Sorry im just new to this